# communication from father to son in angualr

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to communicate from parent to child in angular, where I want the child to receive the data to form a botton or a card, and depending on the data received it would be stylized, but I don't know how I can make the separation[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7psCY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klXON.png)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to create components within child dynamically based on that "body" array?. Passing params from parent to child you can do it by using inputs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, copy/paste the code in the question instead of using images.

now, if you want to pass data from a parent to a child you can use an `Input`
https://angular.io/api/core/Input#usage-notes